# Division by zero - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I am trying to execute following code, I still keep getting this error:

```
    ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Division by zero (View: C:\xampp77\htdocs\resources\views\home.blade.php)
```

Code:

```
           <td class="text-right">
                ${!! number_format($Currency->market_cap_usd,0,',','.') !!}<br>
                <small class="font-italic">{!! number_format($Currency->market_cap_usd / $globalData['BTC_price_usd'],0,',','.')  !!} BTC</small>
           </td>
```

Could somebody help me, or atleast point me in right direction ? Can't figure it out.

Comment: $globalData['BTC_price_usd'] might be 0

Comment: Why would you use 0 for decimals parameter for BTC? That could be very expensive https://3v4l.org/tOGob

Answer (score 0):

$globalData['BTC_price_usd'] is 0 in your code